# Pattern and design for functions that differ greatly from each other but are processed similarly

Tags: python, oop, design-patterns, web-scraping

I'm writing some Python code to scrape websites, and what I'm going to end up with is a growing collection of custom scrapers, each about 50 lines long and tailored extract specific information from a specific website.

My first iteration of the program is one giant file that takes a website as an argument, and scrapes that website if it recognizes it and has custom code for it (using a giant case statement to check if it recognizes the website).

Obviously, this isn't a great design, so what I'd like to do is pull the custom scrape functions into their own files/classes, and have a small script that I can use to call them by name. For example:

```
scrape.py --site google
```

And I'd like to have a file structure similar to:

```
scrape.py
sites/
    google.py
    yahoo.py
    ...
    bing.py
```

I haven't mastered object orientation yet, but I recognize that this is calling out for it, and that what I'm looking for is probably a common OO pattern.

Any help getting this code refactored properly?

PS - I've looked at Scrapy, and it's not really what I need for various reasons.
PPS - I'm not actually scraping search websites, I'm scraping U.S. court websites.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can put the code in a class with an `__init__` method to get everything configured, a `_download` method to connect to the site and download it, a `_store` method to save the results and a `run` method to tie it all together, like so:

```
class Scraper(object):
    def __init__(self, parser, page_generator):
        self._parser = parser
        self._pages = pages

    def _download(self, page):
        # do whatever you're already doing to download it
        return html

    def _store(self, data):
        # Do whatever you're already doing to store the data

    def run(self):
        for page in pages:
            html = self._download(page)
            data = self._parser.parse(html)
            self._store(data)
```

This class can live in your `parser.py` file.

In each one of your site specific files, put two things.

```
class Parser(object):
    def parse(html):
        # All of your rules go here

def pages(some, args, if_, you, need, them): # but they should be the same for all files
    return a_list_of_pages_or_generator
```

Then you can set up your `python.py` file with the following function:

```
def get_scraper(name):
    mod = __import__(name)

    parser = mod.Parser()
    pages = mod.pages() # Pass whatever args you need to figure out the urls

    return Scraper(parser, pages)
```

You can then use it like

```
scraper = get_scraper('google')
scraper.run()
```

Doing it this way has the advantage of not requiring you to make any changes to the `Scraper` class. If you need to do different tricks to get the servers to talk to your scraper, then you can create a `Downloader` class in each module and use it just like the `Parser` class.  If you have two or more parsers that do the same thing, just define them as a generic parser in a separate module and import that into the module of each site that requires it. Or subclass it to make tweaks. Without knowing how you're downloading and parsing the sites, it's hard to be more specific.

My feeling is that you might have to ask several questions to get all of the details ironed out but it will be a good learning experience.

Comment: Ultimately, I used both of the answers to here to build up the [Juriscraper](https://bitbucket.org/mlissner/juriscraper/) library, but borrowed more heavily from this one. Really helpful stuff, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Your technique for refactoring is how I would go. Here is how, I look at implementing this problem.

**First**

I would create a single function called ScrapeHandler in all the files inside the site directory - google.py, yahoo.py etc

```
def ScrapeHandler(...):
    ...
```

**Second**

I would create a __init__.py in sites directory with the following content.

```
scrapers = ["google", "yahoo", ...]
```

**Third**

In the main file scrape.py, I would load the scraper at runtime to choose the appropriate scraping logic.

```
from sites import scrapers
all_scrapers = {}
......
# Load all scrapers
for scraper_name in scrapers:
    all_scrapers[scraper_name] = __import__('%s.%s' % (sites.__name__, scraper_name), fromlist=[scraper_name], level=0)
# get the input on what to scrape via command line etc
scraper_name = ..
assert scraper_name not in scrapers
# call the function based on name 
scrapeHandler = all_scrapers.get(scraper_name, None)
if scrapeHandler is not None:
    scrapeHandler(....)
```

Comment: For the handler, I ended up iterating over the __all__ variable in the module I made, but yeah, good stuff here. Thank you!